# Only trigger once per session at the start of the session

Tags: apache-beam

I am grouping  KV'd pubsub messages into Sessions. I want to know immediately when the session starts. I only want to be informed one time per session.  How do I ensure I only get the one trigger but the Session continues to stay open until the gapDuration is met?

```
apply(Window.<KV<String, PubsubMessage>>into(
                Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(sessionGap)))
                .triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow().withEarlyFirings(AfterProcessingTime.pastFirstElementInPane()))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardMinutes(sessionLateMessageWaitTime))
                .accumulatingFiredPanes()).apply(GroupByKey.create());
```